# Cicles in array to get the absolute difference between every 2 elements of the array

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I want to do a for loops that could basically do the absolute difference between every 2 elements of the array until it reaches all of them and then print the highest absolute difference.

I did another way basically just by only iterating in list once and we will have answer of largest diff. No need to iterate every possible pair of value. Anyways I wanted to compare the response delay that they have. This is the one I did:

```py
list_a = []

n = int(input("number of elements in array: "))        

for i in range(0, n):
    # store input after converting to integer.
    list_a.append(int(input('insert element: ')))
            
'''to store largest difference of two current numbers in every eteration'''
largest_diff_so_far = 0;

'''list to store that two numbers we are comparing'''
actual_diff_number = None;

'''start from first number in list. we don't need to go through every possible pair so just picking first number without for loop.'''
first = list_a[0]
        
'''here we iterate through all number only once till last number in
list'''
for second in list_a :
    '''first find diff of current two value'''
    current_diff = second - first

    '''as we can see when current_diff is larger then previous largest diff we will update their value'''
    if largest_diff_so_far == 0 or current_diff > largest_diff_so_far:

        '''if first value in list is largest than all then the current diff will be negative and in that case we will run below if code and continue the code so that it will not over -ride anything in remaining code'''
        if current_diff < 0:
            ''' since the diff is negative we will store its absolute value in largest diff variable.'''
            largest_diff_so_far = abs(current_diff)

            ''' since first value is largest then all means it is larger than current second also, so in actual_diff_number we will store values in reverse order, so that our largest value which is stored in first variable will be second in list and by this in later iteration we will avoid over-writing of this largest value'''
            actual_diff_number = [second, first]

            ''' we will also update first variable's value to second variable's value since it smaller than previous value of first and by this next iteration will use this value for diff rather than initial value of first variable which was largest.'''
            first = second
            continue

        '''if above condition is not the case than rest of the below code will run'''
        '''largest diff will be current_diff'''
        largest_diff_so_far = current_diff

        '''storing actual number whose diff is largest till now.'''
        actual_diff_number = [first, second]
            
        '''below is main part for saving time. if in current process we find diff which is in minus means our second value is even less than first, in that case we no longer need to carry forward that first value so we will update first value to our current second value and will also update largest diff that is stored previously. since our first value is less than previous first value then our diff will also increase from previous diff.'''
    elif current_diff < 0:
        first = second
        '''update largest diff with new first value'''
        largest_diff_so_far = actual_diff_number[1] - first

        '''update actual diff number's first value in that list'''
        actual_diff_number[0] = first
        
'''finally print answer since after finishing for loop largest_diff_so_far and actual_diff_number contains the answer that we are finding.'''
print(actual_diff_number, largest_diff_so_far)
```

the solution that I'm trying to do now is the same as this one :

Input: {2, 7, 3, 4, 1, 9}

Output: 8 (|1 – 9|)

But I want to get a method using only cicles that can go trought all the elements 2 by 2 and do the absolute diference and then print the highest absolute diference between all the combinations

Answer (score 0):

When thinking about problems like this, you should try your best to split them up into smaller parts. That way you can approach each problem individually.

First a **disclaimer**:

*"Cycles in array"* is too vague. One can convert sequence into 2D array and make literal circles by cycling trough array, then use vector comparison to establish difference, or one can cycle trough array in form of `FOP` (*function oriented programing*) where one just passes data to the functions and they cycle trough it. For more research to boost your terminology I would suggest keywords of `Programming paradigm`, `screen buffer`, `2D list index from 1D list` and `FOP`, `DOP`, `OOP` for starters.
I didn't use `input` function in order to speed up testing. To compensate for user input I've used `choice` function from `random` **`__builtin__`** library.

```
from random import choice; # choice takes in a list or a range as input 
list_a = []; # list to be populated 

def fill_array_random(n):
    global list_a; # global reference for list_a;
    # filling up entire list of N numbers with random values from 0 to 100.
    list_a = [ choice( range(100)) for x in range(n)];
```

After I've gotten my random generated list, it was time to split this problem apart. First thing our program needs to do is **compare 2 values** which you have supplied (**A-B=diff(A,B)**).

---

**Subtraction isn't associative** which means that A-B and B-A aren't the same. It also implies that *minuend* (A) must be greater than *subtrahend* (B) for all differences that are positive. This raises an issue, since in random generated list we don't know if our *minuend* and *subtrahend* will follow this logic, so we have several options how to deal with this:

- We can subtract them as they are, and find the way to deal with negative values
- We can test which one is smaller before we do subtraction, and guarantee positive values.
- We can ignore any value pair that doesn't follow this rule.

Observing your code it seems that you are disregarding negative values (by using `abs()` function. Such function heavily depend on **lookup table** for `data type standards` to make a decision how to make a number absolute, so I have opted out to test which one is smaller.

*Within subtraction if A and B are equal, resulting difference would be 0, and since we are comparing largest positive difference (from 0 to infinity) we should find a way to deal with this situation. For this code, I've chosen to disregard it since only time that this might be important is if all values in list are same.*

```
def compare_items(item1,item2):
    if item1 == item2: return None; # if items are same value, then return None and deal with it later.
    if item1 > item2: # if one is greater than use it in subtraction, and return pair
        return (item1-item2,item1,item2);
    # else (other is greater) swap them in operation.
    return (item2-item1,item1,item2);
```

With this function, only thing I need to keep track of is if result is `None`.

---

**Indices in lists are smaller than lists size**, so if we have list of N items, maximum index we can search for is (N-1) and minimal index is always 0. This presents another issue for our code, if we search for `index` that doesn't exist within a `list` we will have `IndexError` and our program will crash. But since our list goes from 0 to N-1 we can choose from the following:

- Ignore elements at Index 0 or at Index N-1, and find the way to make size of array divisible by 2 (since subtraction requires 2 values).
- Count elements at Index 0 or Index N-1, and find the way to search for them when time comes: (If index is N-2, then search for Index N-1) or (if Index is 0 then search for Index N-1).

Luckily python allow us to use lists to their fullest with 2 independent functionalities:

- `Index at -1` will always return last element in a `list`.
- `Index % ListSize` will always return valid indices for any list of ListSize.

With an given functionality, best solution (for me) seems to be to search for previous item when we get a specific Index to compare them.

```
def generate_indices(Index):
    I1 = Index - 1; # gaining new index of item before one at Index 
    return (I1,Index); # returning both as tuple pair to be tested.
```

There are many ways one can achieve this with one being `range(0,N,step)` where step determines how big of a difference between resulting indices is: `range(0,5,2) -> 0,2,4`.

---

And from all that we get:

```
from random import choice;
list_a = [];

def fill_array_random(n):
    global list_a;
    list_a = [ choice( range(100)) for x in range(n)];

# for user input; 
def fill_array_inquiry():
    global list_a; 
    n = int(input("number of elements in array: "))
    for _ in range(n):
        list_a.append(int(input('insert element: ')))

# function that generates indices for data
def generate_indices(Index):
    I1 = Index - 1;
    return (I1,Index);

# comparison :
def compare_items(item1,item2):
    if item1 == item2: return None;
    if item1 > item2:
        return (item1-item2,item1,item2);
    return (item2-item1,item1,item2);

def run_for_list( list_size ):
    global list_a; # requires that is previously initialized 
    difference = 0; # variable for difference 
    item1 = 0;      # variable for first item of comparison
    item2 = 0;      # variable for second item of comparison

    for i in range(list_size):
        a,b = generate_indices(i); # (i-1,i) 
        dif,i1,i2 = compare_items( list_a[a], list_a[b]);
        
        if dif != None: # list_a[a] and list_a[b] aren't equal;
            # if current difference is larger than previous one 
            if dif > difference: # swap old value with new value 
                difference = dif;
                item1 = i1;
                item2 = i2;
    

    return difference,(item1,item2); # show me what you got.

 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fill_array_random(10);
    print( run_for_list(10));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the time and effort you put into this! I was looking for this but not using def this turns it way easier anyways Ill keep searching!